# Java file system exception when deleting file with NIO Files.delete()

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-integration, nio

I am getting following exception,

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\abcd.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
```

I understand that this file is currently opened by another process but how can you find out which process has lock on this? I'm using this code in spring integration and spring batch where once file is download from ftp server it is delivered to transformer to convert spring integration message to job launch request.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this isn't a coding question, as you will need to use a OS tool that us capable of listing all the Process and associated file locks.  AFAK there is no way to do this directly from within Java itself (you'd either need to run a command line program or hook into native code)

Comment: If you really want to do this through Java, you'll need to use either native code or [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) calling into the native Windows API.  If you really want to do this, [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/17/10268840.aspx) might help you get started.